# python web scraping issue for scraping

Tags: beautifulsoup

I want to scrape text "In stock " from

```
*<p class="instock availability">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
        In stock    
</p>*
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `print(soup.find("i",class_="icon-ok").get_text(strip=True))`

Comment: can we do taking reference to <p> tag because <p> remains unchanged but <i> maybe changed in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @Ahmed said, let:

```
soup = '<p class="instock availability">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
        In stock    
</p>'
```

Now find the tag and get the text by:

```
print(soup.find("i",class_="icon-ok").get_text(strip=True))
```